Downloading Datadog logs via REST API
Can I export datadog logs using the API? Essentially looking for a get call that would take timestamps and index as params. I need to download around 36 million rehydrated logs.

Yes, there is a log list method that can be filtered by date and index. There is also a guide for dealing with the paginated results. You might also want to look at Log Archives as a solution.
